# Display point style on legend in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

https://jsfiddle.net/43Tesseracts/qmhhc089/

For this chart's first dataset `XPData`, how do I set the legend style to use the point instead of the line?

I'm hoping all I need to do is add: `showLines: false` according to the [Scatter Line Chart docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-scatter-line-charts), but I can't figure out where to put this setting.

Here is the data set (see fiddle):

```
var XPData = {
  label: 'XP Earned',
  //fill: false,
  //backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  //borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  pointBorderColor: "#444",
  pointBackgroundColor: "#444",
  data: [],
  showLines: false,
};
```

```js
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

class DataPoint {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

var days = 85;
var chillax = 72.5;

// XP DATA SET 
var XPData = {
  label: 'XP Earned',
  //fill: false,
  //backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  //borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  pointBorderColor: "#444",
  pointBackgroundColor: "#444",
  data: [],
  showLines: false,

  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true
      }
    }
  },
};

// XP Data generation
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
  total += 10 * Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.5);
  total += 5 * Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.5);
  total += 5 * Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.5);

  var p = new DataPoint(i + 1, total);
  XPData.data.push(p);
}


// XP Trend Data     
var XPTrendData = {
  label: 'XP Trend',
  fill: false,
  pointRadius: 0,
  lineTension: 0,
  borderDash: [5, 5],
  borderColor: "#ccc",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  data: [],
};

// XP Trend calculaion
var total = 0;
var days_so_far = XPData.data.length;
total = XPData.data[days_so_far - 1].y;
var average_per_day = total / days_so_far;

var trend_total = total;
for (i = days_so_far; i < days; i++) {

  p = new DataPoint(i, trend_total);
  XPTrendData.data.push(p);
  trend_total += average_per_day;

}

// Chillax Line Data Set
var ChillaxLineData = {
  label: 'Chillax Line',
  pointRadius: 0,
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  borderColor: "#337AB7",
  data: [],
};

// Chill Line Generation
for (i = 1; i < days; i++) {
  p = new DataPoint(i, Math.floor(i * chillax * 10 / days));
  ChillaxLineData.data.push(p);

}

var options = {
  scaleUse2Y: true,

  scales: {

    xAxes: [{
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'bottom',
      ticks: {
        max: days,
        min: 0,
        stepSize: 5,
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Days of Class'
      },
    }],

    yAxes: [{
        id: "y-axis-XP",
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          max: 1000,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 50,
        },

        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'XP'
        },

        gridLines: {},
      },
      {
        id: "y-axis-percent",
        position: 'left',

        ticks: {
          max: 100,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 5,
        },

        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Percent'
        },

        gridLines: {
          /*show: true,
          color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
          lineWidth: 1,
          drawOnChartArea: true,
          drawTicks: true,
          zeroLineWidth: 1,
          zeroLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)", */
        },
      }


    ],
  },

  title: {
    text: 'A Map of Your Progress',
    display: true,
  },

  legend: {
    position: 'top',
  },

};

var data = {
  datasets: [XPData,
    XPTrendData,
    ChillaxLineData,
  ]
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use current library

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>`

add put

```
legend: {
    labels: {
      usePointStyle: true,
    },
  }
```

inside options and not inside `var XPData = {...}`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gv4kyc9o/)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

class DataPoint {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

var days = 85;
var chillax = 72.5;

// XP DATA SET 
var XPData = {
  label: 'XP Earned',
  fill: false,
  backgroundColor: "#444",
  borderColor: "#444",
  pointBorderColor: "#444",
  pointBackgroundColor: "#444",
  data: [],
  showLine: false,
};

// XP Data generation
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
  total += 10 * Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.5);
  total += 5 * Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.5);
  total += 5 * Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.5);

  var p = new DataPoint(i + 1, total);
  XPData.data.push(p);
}


// XP Trend Data     
var XPTrendData = {
  label: 'XP Trend',
  fill: false,
  pointRadius: 0,
  lineTension: 0,
  borderDash: [5, 5],
  borderColor: "#ccc",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  data: [],
};

// XP Trend calculaion
var total = 0;
var days_so_far = XPData.data.length;
total = XPData.data[days_so_far - 1].y;
var average_per_day = total / days_so_far;

var trend_total = total;
for (i = days_so_far; i < days; i++) {

  p = new DataPoint(i, trend_total);
  XPTrendData.data.push(p);
  trend_total += average_per_day;

}

// Chillax Line Data Set
var ChillaxLineData = {
  label: 'Chillax Line',
  pointRadius: 0,
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  borderColor: "#337AB7",
  data: [],
};

// Chill Line Generation
for (i = 1; i < days; i++) {
  p = new DataPoint(i, Math.floor(i * chillax * 10 / days));
  ChillaxLineData.data.push(p);

}



var options = {
  scaleUse2Y: true,

  scales: {

    xAxes: [{
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'bottom',
      ticks: {
        max: days,
        min: 0,
        stepSize: 5,
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Days of Class'
      },
    }],

    yAxes: [{
        id: "y-axis-XP",
        position: 'right',
        ticks: {
          max: 1000,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 50,
        },

        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'XP'
        },

        gridLines: {},
      }, {
        id: "y-axis-percent",
        position: 'left',

        ticks: {
          max: 100,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 5,
        },

        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Percent'
        },

        gridLines: {
          /*show: true,
          color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
          lineWidth: 1,
          drawOnChartArea: true,
          drawTicks: true,
          zeroLineWidth: 1,
          zeroLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)", */
        },
      }


    ],
  },

  title: {
    text: 'A Map of Your Progress',
    display: true,
  },
  legend: {
    labels: {
      usePointStyle: true,
    },
  }

};

var data = {
  datasets: [XPData,
    XPTrendData,
    ChillaxLineData,
  ]
};

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
```

Comment: Awe crap.. I didn't notice but now they are all using point style.  Is it not possible to just set the one dataset to use points?  I don't want points on the line-only data!

Comment: I don't think so it is possible to apply to single data series

Answer (score 7):

you should use code like this in ur options:

```
options: {
    legend: {
       labels: {
           usePointStyle: true
       }
     }
},
```

Comment: I added this but it made no difference. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/qmhhc089/17/

Answer (score 1):

showLine = false,   not showLine**s**.
Then set border/background colors as usual, and legend should show up.

setPointStyle in options will then change the legend to look like a point.

Comment: Can you get the fiddle to work?  I tried adding usePointStyle with no luck: https://jsfiddle.net/qmhhc089/17/

Comment: Per below, setPointStyle starts working from v. 2.2.0.  And needs to be under legend: {labels: {setPointStyle:true},}