# Change Radius/Point size of Legend Points in chart.js when usePointStyle is true

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to reduce the point size of legend items

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajatjain4061/nk6pdfs6/2/)

I tried all available options given in the documentation but nothing worked

Javascript Code

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
        labels: {
            usePointStyle:true
      }
    },
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Html

```
<canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hope this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173081/chart-js-styling-legend/43173497

Comment: @Umair I already saw that but click function will not work on custom legends

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `boxWidth` option to influence the size of the point in the legend:

```
options: {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      usePointStyle: true,
      boxWidth: 6
    }
  }
}
```

Looking at the chartjs code (version 2.8), `boxWidth` is used as long as it is smaller than `fontSize`. `fontSize` is used as it gets larger than `boxWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the documentation of chartjs about legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html):

> **usePointStyle**
>
> Label style will match corresponding point style (size is based on fontSize, boxWidth is not used in this case).

So just by adding:

```
...
labels: {
  fontSize: 2,
    usePointStyle:true,
}
...
```

[JSFiddle with the modified size](https://jsfiddle.net/e8sn0uft/)

You get the size of the legend points smaller.

[image: Size 42]
[image: Size 2]

Maybe I understood you wrong, if so leave a comment and I will modify my answer to fit the new question

Comment: What about *only* changing the point size and not the font size?

Comment: Well, that code wise is not possible since in the code (https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/6bea15e7cf89003e3a5945a20cf1d2cc5096728e/src/plugins/plugin.legend.js#L92) you pass the fontSize to calc the size of the point and also the label text

Comment: That's such a shame

Comment: Yes... I don't know what motivated chartjs to not provided an additional parameter for that size