# ChartJS legend background color while using point styles

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In my chart I'm using Points to create rounded circles like
[image]

```
{
    id: 7,
    label: 'Sample 1',
    borderColor: '#ff3f0c',
    backgroundColor: '#ff3f0c',
    pointBorderColor: '#ff3f0c',
    pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointBorderWidth: 1,
    pointRadius: 5,
    fill: false,
    data: [0, 5, 2, 0, 3, 3, 5, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0]
},
```

The problem with this is that my bottom legend is inheriting the dot style, more specifically the `pointBackgroundColor` which is white. [image]

The chart tooltip also suffers from the same problem. It doesn't need to be rounded, but it's filling the background color with white.

[image]

The inherits occurs with the code:

```
legend:
{
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom',
    labels:
    {
        boxWidth: 10,
        usePointStyle: true
    }
},
```

My goal:

1. The chart dots be rounded and have white background
2. The chart legend be rounded and inherit the background in the `backgroundColor` property
3. The chart tooltip be square and inherit the background in the `backgroundColor` property

JSFiddle to see the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/0eLtkzmy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**.

1. The solution is to maintain the code as it is
2. The solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43173498/3355243
3. The solution is below

Applies the colors of the tooltips taking in consideration the dataset index.

```
options:
{
    tooltips:
    {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
        callbacks:
        {
            labelColor: function(tooltipItem, chart)
            {
                var datasetIndex = tooltipItem.datasetIndex;
                var borderColor = chart.legend.legendItems[datasetIndex].fillStyle;
                var backgroundColor = chart.legend.legendItems[datasetIndex].fillStyle;

                return {
                    borderColor: borderColor,
                    backgroundColor: backgroundColor
                };
            },
        }
    },
}
```